# Which of Homebrew or mas-cli to choose when a package is available via both?

Tags: homebrew, mac-appstore

I'm using the opportunity of a new Mac laptop to get to grips with automating the post-macOS-installation setup process, rather than going through the usual mind-numbing click-fest or crud-inheriting Migration Assistant.

I read a few articles to get started, and most suggested using `Homebrew` but as a first step they recommended using brew to install `mas` (see [github)](https://github.com/mas-cli/mas), the command-line interface to the Mac App Store. I'm making fair progress with that, but my question is this:

When a particular package is available via both `Homebrew` and `mas` (and that often seems to be the case -- 1Password 7 is a current example), does it matter which one is used? (And if it does, what things should be considered when choosing?)

Comment: @Nimesh Neema, thanks for the edits. I've left in your mention of "Mac App Store", but I'd prefer to keep the primary reference being to mas itself. I *happened* to know that mas interfaces to the App Store, but others using this question in future might not, in which case a search for Homebrew and mas might not find this. Thanks again, though, for the edit (and your answer). :-)

Answer (score 2):

Both the Mac App Store (to which the mas you mention is a command-line interface) and Homebrew are package managers in their own rights, only difference being that former comes from 1st party while the latter is a open-source, community developed one.

The end result in either case is almost the same (the app bundle getting installed under `/Applications` directory). Below are some differences in terms of how the package management (installation/uninstallation) gets affected in either case, which helps in making a decision with which one to choose:

1. Using Homebrew lets one script and automate the package management.
2. Homebrew allows access to `zap` verb, which alongside uninstalling the app also deletes any associated metadata file(s).
3. Installing via Homebrew may let you gain access to the latest version of the app earlier than the Mac App Store, as the update released via latter wait for the approval from the App Store review team.

   On the other hand, an update released via Mac App Store is assured to have passed through the review team.
4. Most often the apps made available via either would align in their version number (except for the brief period of time when the version numbers mismatch as an update waits for review), and you should be able to install it either way without much of a difference.
5. Unless if there's an app which is still available on the App Store, but no longer sees any updates, but gets updates via Homebrew, going either way would let you get access to the latest version.

Taking into consideration all of the above, here's an approach that I take personally. If an app sees active updates on both the platforms, I prefer installing it via Homebrew over Mac App Store.

Comment: Applications like 1Password are available via Casks, so they basically just the binaries (from the agilebits.com download section) distributed via Homebrew.

Comment: @nohillside, thanks. This is pretty much the second question I asked Nimesh above: how do you *know* that the 1Password I'd get via Homebrew is the legit one from agile.bits? And for packages in general, how safe is using Homebrew; i.e. how do we know, for any given package, that what's being installed is what we think is being installed?

Comment: @tkp At the end of the day you need to trust the volunteers maintaining the Homebrew formulas. So if you want to be sure you need to download from the Store (directly, not via mas-cli) or from agilebits.com. Especially for 1P I don't see a lot of value in Homebrew, it auto-updates itself anyway.